# Rails - Format number as currency format in the Getter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency

I am making a simple retail commerce solution, where there are **prices** in a few different models. These prices contribute to a **total price**. Imagine paying $0.30 more for selecting a topping for your yogurt.

When I set the `price` field to

```
t.decimal   :price, precision:8, scale:2
```

The database stores `6.50` as `6.5`. I know in the standard rails way, you call `number_to_currency(price)` to get the formatted value in the Views. I need to programmatically call the `price` field as well formatted string, i.e. $6.50 a few places that are not directly part of the View. Also, my needs are simple (no currency conversion etc), I prefer to have the price formatted universally in the model without repeated calling number_to_currency in views.

Is there a good way I can modify my getter for price such that it always returns two decimal place with a dollar sign, i.e. $6.50 when it's called?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Thanks everyone.

I've elected to use Alex's approach because it seems very 'hackish' to do the includes just for formatting the number. Using his approach, I did:

```
  def price_change=(val)
      write_attribute :price_change, val.to_s.gsub(/[\$]/,'').to_d
  end

  def price_change
    "$%.2f" % self[:price_change]
  end
```

Cheers.

**UPDATE 2**

Caveat Emptor. Once you do this, you lose the ability to do operations to the number because it's now a string.

Please beware if anyone is facing the same problem as me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add a method in your model which is named like your attribute in the database like:

```
def price
   "$%.2f" % self[:price]
end
```

which gives you full control over the formatting or use the Rails provided helper method

```
def price
   ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_currency(self[:price])
end
```

this should do the trick.
hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! Was thinking there must be some number formatting built in. A little bit wary of including ActionView or ActionController into the model.

Comment: The problem with this is you can no use the price as a number, it is a string everywhere. I am looking for a way to make the rails helper convert it this way on the to_s

Answer (score 4):

You can use the helpers module, but you should not include the whole module, because it includes a lot of methods which you may not really need or overrides some of yours. But you can use them directly:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_currency(6.5)   
#=> "$6.50"
```

You could also define a method for the helpers, so you can easily use them.

```
def helpers
  ActionController::Base.helpers
end

"#{helpers.number_to_currency(6.5)}"
```

Have a look at this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/132-helpers-outside-views)

Comment: Thanks man. Like above, a bit wary of this, seems to break MVC. I'll actually try out both =)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest going with a Presenter approach, like Draper (see [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper) reailscast) does.

Another solution would be to implement your own method in your model, i.e. `formatted_price` and do the formatting on your own, (i.e. with the `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` module). But since models represent the plain data in your rails application, it's kinda shady doing something like this and it interferes with the convention over configuration approach, I think.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

to your model